# Does dish soap exhibit effects when washing non-fatty dishes?

Tags: cleaning

I know that a soap's main effect is to bind fats to water, i.e., to make fatty substances water-soluble. When washing fat-free dishes, e.g., a bowl that was only used to temporarily hold a can of tomato sauce, I wonder whether there is any point in using dish soap, or whether rinsing with water is just as good?

Assumptions:

- Only fat-free foods were used in the dish, such as many vegetables or fruit.
- No relevant skin fats from mouth or fingers, i.e., I am *not* asking about glasses that someone drank from, cutlery, or items that where touched/handled a lot.
- Ignore pure optical effects of dish soap, e.g., substances to make glass shinier.

Does dish soap (detergent) have relevant effects in such cases?

Comment: It might be helpful to clarify.  What do you mean by "exhibit effects."  Your question already eliminates  main effect of soap (creating an emulsion)....so I'm not sure what you want to know?  It is certainly possible to clean dishes and kitchen items without soap.

Comment: I think my question boils down to whether without soap there is a higher risk of food remains being left on the dishes, providing grounds for, e.g., bacterial growth.

Comment: These are two different questions.  1. Does soap facilitate the removal of food from dishes...and 2. Is soap necessary to sanitize dishes?  I would still suggest rewording your question.

Comment: What's the practical application of this information - are you going to leave one dish on the side to just give a quick rinse later, whilst ensuring the rest get a good soapy wash?

Comment: @moscafj One partially implies the other, does it not? My question is about daily household use, so I am not sure I see the point in getting scientific (I suppose we can sanitize dishes but leave food on the dishes, e.g., by heating it to high temperatures, etc.)?

Comment: @unlisted For example, I might quickly rinse a bowl (partial cleanup while still cooking). Other dishes are placed in the dishwasher later.

Comment: Just put the whole lot in the dishwasher. It's hugely uneconomical [both in financial & "green" terms] to be hand-washing bit by bit. Once everything that will go in the dishwasher has gone in it, everything that *must* be hand washed can be done in one go.

Comment: This question is not about economics. Do you think it is better suited for https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: I for sure only rinse out bowls that held cut vegetables, or a knife I used to slice a tomato, for example, if nothing is stuck. I don't know if I am missing anything, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While not all foods have visible fat, anything that came from plant or animal cells will have trace amounts of lipids (building blocks of fat) and lipid-soluble/non-polar  (like to bind with oils & fats) compounds. These include:

- lycopene, the pigment that gives tomatoes their red colour
- capsaicin, the spice in peppers
- various other volatile compounds that contribute to tastes and smells

Since plastics have a non-polar composition, these compounds easily adhere to plastic food containers and can bind strongly enough to resist being rinsed off with plain water. Length of contact time between food and container, and the specific type of plastic used, affect this. These compounds can also form thin films on glass  with the trace amounts of lipids present. Surfactant ingredients in soaps help remove these as you described in conjunction with agitation from scrubbing.

One way you can test this is rubbing the skin of a tomato, rind of a cucumber, some tumeric, or ghost peppers on a clear bowl and see/smell the residue from rinsing vs soap washing.

Additionally, as noted by @Tristan Beckwith above, some soaps will have bactericidal additives. [Most surfactant ingredients will have some capacity to kill microorganisms](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/24827732/#:%7E:text=Surfactants%20have%20a%20striking%20similarity,this%20interaction%20is%20concentration%20dependent.), but for consistently achievable results - i.e. in a commercial food service setting - the application of heat or use of chemical sanitizers are needed.

Comment: Interesting. Is this (the lycopene adherance) the reason why, e.g., tomato sauce stains plastics?

Comment: Yes, that's the reason. To build on that, difficult lipid-soluble pigment stains can be removed by using non-polar solvents like isopropyl (rubbing) alcohol, maybe with an extended soak for older stains. Very, very old stains may completely resist removal if the pigments have migrated past the surface layer of plastic.

Answer (score 0):

The dish soap Dawn's active ingredient is "chloroxylenol" and it is a disinfectant that kills bacteria. This means that there is a difference between washing with soap and washing with water.

Comment: Chloroxylenol is *not* the (only) active ingredient in soaps  containing it; listing it as such is done to conform with FDA regulations for pharmaceutical labeling. The actual active ingredients (detergents) are generally more effective than disinfectants at actually disinfecting.

Comment: Is this an US-specific ingredient? I checked a couple products here (Europe) and did not come across this.